# Frete correios erro no pac e no sedex

Tags: php, web-service

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês nos seguintes erros, o primeiro é no pac, ele retornar o valor, até ai tudo certo, porém ele também traz:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active
>   file]

Retorna o valor correto da transação mas também retorna esse fatal erro e não entendo porque.

Já no Sedex ele sempre me traz o erro -5, olhei na API dos correios e quanto aos códigos dos serviços, bem... são os mesmos, não consigo entender porque me retorna esse erro -5. Procurei no google mas não encontrei nada a respeito desse erro.

Meu form

```
<form method="POST" action="carrinhoo.php" enctype="">
   <select name="frete" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Selecione...</option>
      <option value="carta">Carta Registrada</option>
      <option value="pac">Pac</option>
      <option value="sedex">Sedex</option>
   </select>
   Digite seu cep:<br>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep"><br>
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="acao" value="calcular">
   <input type="submit" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-success">
    Valor frete: <?php echo ($_SESSION['valor_frete'] == '6.00') ? number_format($_SESSION['valor_frete'],2,',','.') : $_SESSION['valor_frete'];?>
 </form>
```

Aqui é feita a requisição:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'calcular'){
        $frete = $_POST['frete'];
        $cep = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cep'));
        switch ($frete){
            case 'carta':
                $valor = '6.00';
                $_SESSION['valor_frete'] = '6.00';
            break;
            case 'pac':
                $valor = '41106';
                $prod = new Produto();
                $_SESSION['valor_frete'] = $prod->CalculaFrete($valor, 45350000, $cep, '0.50');
            break;
            case 'sedex':
                $valor = '40010';
                $prod = new Produto();
                $_SESSION['valor_frete'] = $prod->CalculaFrete($valor, 45350000, $cep, '0.50');
                var_dump($_SESSION['valor_frete']);
            break;    
        }
    }
```

Aqui meu método com a API dos correios

```
public function CalculaFrete($cod_servico, $cep_origem, $cep_destino, $peso, $altura = '2', $largura = '11', $comprimento = '16', $valor_declarado = '0.50'){
        $correios = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?"."nCdEmpresa=&sDsSenha=&sCepOrigem=".$cep_origem.
               "&sCepDestino=".$cep_destino."&nVlPeso=".$peso."&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=".$comprimento."&nVlAltura=".$altura.
               "&nVlLargura=".$largura."&sCdMaoPropria=n"."&nVlValorDeclarado=".$valor_declarado."&sCdAvisoRecebimento=n".
               "&nCdServico=".$cod_servico."&nVlDiametro=0&StrRetorno=xml";

        $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($correios));
        if($xml->cServico->Erro == '0'){
            return $xml->cServico->Valor;
        }else{
            var_dump($xml);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uma dica, ao invés de `strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cep'))` use `preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST['cep']);`, assim ele vai remover qualquer coisa que não seja (`^`) um número de 0 a 9 (`0-9`).

Comment: cara na boa pega o retorno em json bem mais facil d processar

Answer (score 1):

Depois de horas fuçando consegui resolver os 2 problemas, na verdade nem eram tão difíceis mas levei umas 5 horas para descobrir o que acontecia. Sobre o erro -5 que dava no Sedex tem haver com exceção de valores, no caso do Sedex simples que é o que eu uso ele tem o seguintes limites de valores 10 reais e 10.000, ou seja, ele não envia produtos com o valor <= 10 e nem > 10.000.
No caso do **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]**, esse já foi mais difícil, parece que pelo que andei lendo até o php 5.3 não ocorria esse tipo de erro no webservice dos correios, como uso a versão 5.6 acontece essa exception.

O simplexml_load_string () não pode ser serializado. Uma tentativa de fazê-lo resultará em uma falha de tempo de execução, lançando uma exceção. Se você armazenar tal objeto receberá um erro de pós-execução.

Resumindo não poderia passar o objeto diretamente, e sim como string, então fiz isso.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($correios));

        if($xml->cServico->Erro == '0'){
            $xm = (string)$xml->cServico->Valor;
            return $xm;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

`Erro -5` é o valor declarado superior a R$ 10.000,00.

Todos os erros do webservice...

```
CodE    Erro

10  CEP de destino est  temporariamente sem entrega domiciliar. A entrega ser  efetuada na agˆncia indicada no Aviso de Chegada que ser  entregue no endere‡o do destinat rio

11  CEP de destino est  sujeito a condi‡äes especiais de entrega pela ECT e ser  realizada com o acr‚scimo de at‚ 7 (sete) dias £teis ao prazo regular.

-40 Para definicao do preco deverao ser informados, tambem, o comprimento e a largura e altura do objeto em centimetros (cm).

-11 Para defini‡Æo do pre‡o deverÆo ser informados, tamb‚m, o comprimento, a largura e altura do objeto em cent¡metros (cm).

-32 A soma resultante do comprimento + o dobro do diƒmetro nÆo deve superar a 200 cm.

-23 A soma resultante do comprimento + largura + altura nÆo deve superar a 200 cm.

-43 A soma resultante do comprimento + largura nao deve superar a 120 cm.

-33 Sistema temporariamente fora do ar. Favor tentar mais tarde.

-38 Servi‡o indispon¡vel para este c¢digo administrativo.

7   Localidade de destino nÆo abrange o servi‡o informado

-36 Cliente nÆo possui contrato vigente com os Correios.

6   Localidade de origem nÆo abrange o servi‡o informado

-37 Cliente nÆo possui servi‡o ativo em seu contrato.

-10 Precifica‡Æo indispon¡vel para o trecho informado

-7  O Valor Declarado ‚ obrigat¢rio para este servi‡o

-5  O Valor Declarado nÆo deve exceder R$ 10.000,00

-42 O comprimento nao pode ser inferior a 16 cm.

-30 O comprimento nÆo pode ser inferior a 18 cm.

-28 O comprimento nÆo pode ser maior que 105 cm.

-22 O comprimento nÆo pode ser inferior a 16 cm.

-15 O comprimento nÆo pode ser maior que 105 cm.

-9  Este servi‡o nÆo aceita Aviso de Recebimento

-6  Servi‡o indispon¡vel para o trecho informado

8   Servi‡o indispon¡vel para o trecho informado

-41 O comprimento nao pode ser maior que 60 cm.

-34 C¢digo Administrativo ou Senha inv lidos.

-44 A largura nao pode ser inferior a 11 cm.

-31 O diƒmetro nÆo pode ser inferior a 5 cm.

-29 O diƒmetro nÆo pode ser maior que 91 cm.

-20 A largura nÆo pode ser inferior a 11 cm.

-16 A largura nÆo pode ser maior que 105 cm.

9   CEP inicial pertencente a µrea de Risco.

-45 A largura nao pode ser maior que 60 cm.

-17 A altura nÆo pode ser maior que 105 cm.

-18 A altura nÆo pode ser inferior a 2 cm.

7   Servi‡o indispon¡vel, tente mais tarde

-39 Peso excedido para o formato envelope

-8  Este servi‡o nÆo aceita MÆo Pr¢pria

99  Outros erros diversos do .Net

-1  C¢digo de servi‡o inv lido

0   Processamento com sucesso

-888    Erro ao calcular a tarifa

-3  CEP de destino inv lido

-26 Informe o comprimento.

-2  CEP de origem inv lido

-24 Comprimento inv lido.

-12 Comprimento inv lido.

-27 Informe o diƒmetro.

-25 Diƒmetro inv lido

-13 Largura inv lida.

-35 Senha incorreta.

-14 Altura inv lida.

-4  Peso excedido
```

Comment: Seria interessante que você fizesse um resumo na sua resposta e indicasse o link da sua fonte, assim não precisaria dessa lista imensa de erros e descrições.

Comment: Isso era para ser uma resposta à pergunta?

Comment: Desculpem minha ignorância, só queria ajudar a comunidade caso de outros erros. Não irei mais postar nada além do perguntado. A fonte é o site dos Correios.